# Is projection method really applicable for numerical solution of linear integral equations in $ L^p \ (p \neq 2)$ setting?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, soft-question, na.numerical-analysis

Projection method is a traditional method to numerically handle problem of linear integral equation. The routine way is to do it in $ L^2 $ setting. For example:

Let $ A:L^2(a,b) \to L^2(a,b) $ be a compact injective operator. We introduce a sequence of basis subspace $ X_n := \{ \xi_k\}^n_{k=1} $, which is increasing and eventually dense in $ L^2(a,b) $, that is, 
\begin{equation*}
X_n \subseteq X_{n+1}, \overline{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n} =L^2(a,b).
\end{equation*}
Then define a sequence of orthogonal projection operator $ \{ P_n \} $, which project $ L^2(a,b) $ onto $ X_n $. Now for $ y \in \mathcal{R}(A) $, $ A^\dagger_n y_n $ could be a natural approximate scheme to $ A^{-1} y $, where 
\begin{equation*}
A_n := P_n A P_n : X_n \longrightarrow X_n \ \text{and} \ y_n := P_n y \in X_n
\end{equation*}
(Of course we could describe above system in a inner product form).
The convergence result could be seen in [Theorem 13.6] of

> R. Kress: Linear Integral Equations, Springer-Verlag, Berlin,
>   1989.

However, we notice that the convergence analysis permits the compact operator $ A $ to be defined in Banach space ($ L^p $), but we have not seen a numerical example with projection procedure in $ L^p $ setting. So we want to know if this convergence result in $ L^p $ setting is of practical value? or only of theoretical importance?

If the former, please indicate some references with numerical example which handle linear integral equation with projection method in $ L^p $ setting.

Thank you in advance!